# Python MySQLdb module: can you insert or update without calling string format?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

For Python module [`MySQLdb`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/), I would like to insert or update the database without doing a `str()` on my data (like int or float or whatever). I have version 1.2.3.

I googled around, looked at many different examples, and checked the API docs and all the examples I found for doing a database insert or update require doing generating a string from your int or float data and then calling the `cursor.execute()`.

**For Python module [`MySQLdb`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/), can you insert or update without calling string format on integers or floats? If yes, how?**

(
As an aside, I'm not a fan of converting python int/float to str for an insert because it costs CPU and then the receiving mysql server process then has to do the str to int/float conversion which also costs CPU again. Additionally for floats if you do the string representation wrong... your float can lose precision ... or there is rounding sometimes... etc etc.
)

Answer (score 1):

If you would use *query parameterization*, `MySQLdb` would do the Python-to-database type conversion automatically under-the-hood:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE table SET field = %s", (value, ))
```

Note how the query parameters passed separately in a tuple. And, you don't need to put quotes around placeholders in the query - the driver would also handle it.

Comment: So the `value` is not converted to a string inside of the call to `cursor.execute()`?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith it can be converted not only to a string, but to an appropriate type depending on a Python type of a parameter - mysqldb will figure it out automagically under-the-hood.